# Wrong CacheManager is looked up Spring ehcache

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

i'm trying to configure ehcache with spring anotations for my project and i'm getting this Exception:

Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] to required type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager] for property 'cacheManager'

My context aplication file is this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd       
   http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
   http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-        spring-1.1.xsd">
<ehcache:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"     p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache" />
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"/>
</beans>
```

What i'm i doing wrong? if i change the rg.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager for net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager i get another exception.

Thanks for any help u can give me.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manually creating a Spring CacheManager and it's being implicitly used (due to it's "cacheManager" id) by `annotation-driven` mechanism. The annotation mechanism will actually do that for you, but it's needs the underlying cache implementation. So change your code to the following:

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" 
    p:configLocation="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"/>
```

NOTE: you can get rid of

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"     p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache" />
```

Comment: Thanks, i've been able to deploy my project, @user2264997 but now i get the impression that it isn't doing any cache at all :(, do u know how can y check that? (i know is not part of the initial question but i would really help me)

Comment: assuming you have an "admin" interface/server in your application, just inject the "cacheManager" to your admin service, get the [`Cache`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html) you want to inspect and dump it's contents.